# Баг с relative в css?

Tags: html, css

Указатель не смещается вниз:

HTML:

```
<div class="notice">
    Пароль или имя пользователя указано не верно
    <div class="pointer">▼</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notice {
    position: absolute;
}
    .notice .pointer {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
```

Таким образом ▼ должен быть смещён на 50 пикселей в низ, но этого не происходит

Comment: Нет. Просто добавьте `top: 50px;`. `margin-bottom -50px` сработает с `absolute` и прочими

Comment: Меня интересует почему мой способ не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.notice .pointer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, работает. Что самое интересное если выносить указатель вверх, тогда он выходит за пределы блока

Comment: не подскажете, почему мой способ не работает?

Comment: Это тонкости блочного позиционирования. В документации где то можно найти-- уже не помню )